# OutOfMemory when adding multiple images to a list

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, bitmap

I let the user pick images, these images get stored in a list.
When adding 20 images (more or less), i get an outOfMemory error.

The images i'm using are 13MB each, so when adding 20 images, 260 MB
is loaded in memory. This isn't much, why does it crash?

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";

            dlg.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg,*.png)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ++totalNrPages;

                if (cbxInsertPage.Checked)
                {
                    //add page after pageIndex
                    Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
                    scanController.InsertPage(img, pageIndex + 1);
                    ChangePage(pageIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    //add page to the end
                    scanController.AddPage(Bitmap.FromFile(dlg.FileName));
                    ChangePage(totalNrPages - 1);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The insertPage method:

```
private List<ScannedPage> scannedPages = new List<ScannedPage>();

public void InsertPage(Image img, int pageIdx)
{
   scannedPages.Insert(pageIdx, new ScannedPage(img));
}
```

Comment: Do you do that repaetedly without ever disposing of them?? Note that this is up to you! Images and other GDI resources will not the garbage collected like regular managed items!

Comment: I assume the images are 13 MiB *compressed* - likely a JPEG, right? That can easily expand above the 32-bit memory line uncompressed. Also note that `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown for some GDI errors too (including "unknown/wrong image format").

Comment: i dispose them when they are not needed anymore, but the images are shown in a picturebox so when the form is visible i'd like to keep them in memory.

Comment: @Luaan, all the images i add to the list are png

Comment: Png is also compressed, just a llittle less!

Comment: The images aren't kept in memory as PNG, they're kept as raw bitmaps. How large is the PNG when you change it to a 32-bit bitmap? :)

Comment: What pixel sizes do those 20 images have?

Comment: I think you should use a different approach you just sort the images name only. render images directly on the form instead of loading them in memory first and then using them on form

Comment: Thx for the advice i'll check the file size as bitmap and try a different approach